# Antshares (NEO) algorithm (dbft) - Vulnerability to attacks - Game theory

Tags: algorithm-design

This is more a game theory question, I think that this Forum is the best for this question.

Please also correct me at the following text if I write something wrong. I understand the consensus algorythm (delegated byzantine fault tolerance (dbft)) of Antshares or NEO like this:

Nodes have a voting power and they can vote for one or more Bookkeeper nodes. Bookkepper nodes are involved in the consensus process. A node is not involved in the consensus process. One bookkepper node is selected by the system to broadcast it's version of the blockchain. Bookkeeper nodes need to agree with 66% on a version of the blockchain. If 66% is not reached then the next bookkeeper node broadcasts it's version and so on.

Now my questions:

1) What happens if no consensus is reached? Endlessloop and nothing happens?

2) Can a node also be a virtual machine? I mean if so it would be much easier to attack the system and elect malicious bookkeeper nodes.

3) If 33% of elected bookkepper nodes are malicious, is the system then destroyed?